# How to trigger an expression on selecting an option in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following code wrapped in ng-repeat

```
<select class="selectpicker input input-halfwide">
     <option disabled selected> -- Select your destination -- </option>
     <option ng-repeat="(key, country) in home.List" value="key" ng-model="home.status.selectedOption">{{country.title}}
     </option>
</select>
```

I want that when the user selects an option, to perform the expression home.doSomething() in the controller.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with an `ng-change` on the select:

```
<select class="selectpicker input input-halfwide"
        ng-model="home.status.selectedOption"
        ng-change="home.doSomething()">
    <option disabled selected> -- Select your destination -- </option>
    <option ng-repeat="(key, country) in home.List" value="{{ key }}"
            ng-selected="{{ key == home.status.selectedOption }}">
        {{country.title}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Also note that I moved the `ng-model` directive to the `select` instead of the `option` element.

---

A better practice would be to use the `ng-options` directive:

```
<select class="selectpicker input input-halfwide"
        ng-model="home.status.selectedOption"
        ng-change="home.doSomething()"
        ng-options="country.id as country.name for country in home.List">
    <option disabled selected> -- Select your destination -- </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `ng-change` to detect selection change and `ng-model` for the selected value on `select`.

```
<select class="selectpicker input input-halfwide" ng-change="home.doSomething()" ng-model="home.status.selectedOption">
   <option disabled selected> -- Select your destination -- </option>
   <option ng-repeat="(key, country) in home.List" value="key">{{country.title}}</option>
</select>
```

now, in your controller you can directly use the selected value using `$scope`

```
$scope.home.doSomething = function () {
    // $scope.home.status.selectedOption
};
```